# Can past sense verb follow “in this moment”?

Tags: grammar, tenses

I’m confused about the tense of this sentence:

[Now they’re in this moment where they were planning to release a bill last week.](https://www.npr.org/2020/07/27/895651297/morning-news-brief)

Is it grammatically correct?
And I also want to know whether there’s any difference between “in this moment where” and “ in this moment when”. Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct but does not show the best idiomaticity, in my opinion. Something such as the following would have seemed more usual to me.

- Now they've reached this moment [during which/when/where] they were planning to release a bill last week.

There is no difference as to meaning; "where" can be used to stand for places, situations and stages ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where)).
The particular moment mentioned can be identified to a given situation or stage in a progression.
The given form used communicates somewhat different connotations. For instance the same general idea could have been written like so:

- "Now they are at the point where  they were planning to release a bill last week.".

Comment: So it means according to the plan that they had last week they should release the bill at the moment?

Comment: @ZaneHsu No, it means "according to the plan they had at this moment (a moment possibly one month before the week mentioned) they should release the bill last week.".

Comment: @ZaneHsu To have a meaning approaching that which you mention the sentence should be "Now they’re in this moment, last week, where they were planning to release a bill.", and there is no teelling when the release will be.

Comment: "*Now they are the point*"? ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford No, of course not, that's a typing error; I will add the missing preposition.